# Cannot call value of non-function type '((Selector) -> Bool)!' converting to Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

```
if (model.classForCoder.respondsToSelector("rangeKeyAttribute")) {
    let rangeKeyAttribute = model.classForCoder.rangeKeyAttribute!()
    let index = keys.indexOf(rangeKeyAttribute)
    if let index = index {
        keys.removeAtIndex(index)
        keys.insert(rangeKeyAttribute, atIndex: 0)
    }
}
```

This code used to work fine, but in Swift 3 the compiler said this is deprecated and this:

```
if (model.classForCoder.respondsToSelector("rangeKeyAttribute")) {
```

Should be changed to:

```
if (model.classForCoder.responds(to: #selector(AWSDynamoDBModeling.rangeKeyAttribute))) {
```

Swift 3 doesn't like this and is throwing the error:

Cannot call value of non-function type '((Selector) -> Bool)!'

I can't seem to figure out how to make it Swift 3 acceptable!

Comment: Maybe discard the if statement and write `if let rangeKeyAttribute = model.classForCoder.rangeKeyAttribute?()` directly?

Comment: call it like `if (model.classForCoder.responds(to: #selector(rangeKeyAttribute()))) {}`

Comment: Leo: Same error, rptwsthi: "Use of unresolved identifier rangeKeyAttribute"

Sweeper: That worked!!! Thank you so much!